# Foundation CSS order with side menu

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using [Foundation](https://get.foundation/sites/docs) and I would like to create this grid on small devices: [image]

And make it look like this on desktop: [image]

You can see that "Actions" and "Sideinfo" are now in the side nav.

That's what I have so far:

```css
.actions { background-color: #00FFF7; height: 5rem !important; padding: .5rem; }
.about { background-color: #F0A202; height: 10rem !important; padding: .5rem; }
.side { background-color: #00FFF7; height: 7rem !important; padding: .5rem; }
.copyright { background-color: #F0A202; height: 12rem !important; padding: .5rem; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .actions {
    order: 3;
  }

  .about {
    order: 1;
  }

  .side {
    order: 4;
  }

  .copyright {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.7.4/dist/css/foundation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.7.4/dist/css/foundation-prototype.min.css" />


<div class="grid-container padding-top-1">
  <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x grid-margin-y align-top">
    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4 large-3 float-left actions">
      <h1>Actions</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="cell small-12 medium-8 large-9 float-right about">
      <h1>About this item</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4 large-3 float-left side">
      <h1>Sideinfo</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="cell small-12 medium-8 large-9 float-right copyright">
      <h1>Copyright</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see it here as well: https://codepen.io/DoctorRobot/pen/WNMJOMq

You can see the `order` doesn't look to be the right solution. I tried to use float-right and float-left but it doesn't look to match what I want. Any ideas and suggestions?

Comment: What you have on the big screen is a so-called masonry layout, I don't think it can be achieved by using just foundation's grid. You could try and having all the four boxes in a ".small-12" together and then use flex and ordering to get that layout

Comment: Thanks @JonasGrumann I'll keep trying without using Masonry. There must be a way somehow.

Comment: Maybe with grids but even with that it could be tricky because the rows will stretch if the content grows

Answer (score 0):

`order` would only be ideal for the layout when changing the order for mobile devices. I am not an expert on [Foundation Flexbox Utilities](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/flexbox-utilities.html) by any means but this should work nicely for you. I essentially grouped the `div`'s in twos under their respective `.cell .small-12 etc`. I also removed the `float`'s as they don't work great with `flex`.

I used your existing media queries to get your desired `margin` on desktop and mobile. I'm not sure if there is a way to specify `margin` or `gap` using foundation but I would use them if you are able.

```css
.actions {
  background-color: #00FFF7;
  height: 5rem !important;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.about {
  background-color: #F0A202;
  height: 10rem !important;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.side {
  background-color: #F18805;
  height: 7rem !important;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.copyright {
  background-color: #D95D39;
  height: 12rem !important;
  padding: .5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .about,
  .actions,
  .copyright,
  .side {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .actions {
    order: 1;
  }
  .about {
    order: 2;
  }
  .side {
    order: 3;
  }
  .copyright {
    order: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.7.4/dist/css/foundation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.7.4/dist/css/foundation-prototype.min.css" />

<div class="grid-container padding-top-1">
  <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x grid-margin-y align-top">
    <div class="cell small-12 medium-8 large-9 about">
      <h1>About this item</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4 large-3 actions">
      <h1>Actions</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-12 medium-8 large-9 copyright">
      <h1>Copyright</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4 large-3 side">
      <h1>Sideinfo</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think you missed the point showing that the order on mobile is: "Actions, About, Sideinfo, Copyright" but on Desktop it should be on the left "About, Copyright" and on the right "Actions, Sideinfo"

Comment: @onda47 Sorry I am just seeing this. Please see the adjustments. That should work for you. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: In your example, "Sideinfo" is aligned with "Copyright" which isn't something I want. Also "Actions" should be at the top in mobile view. I had a similar idea but it doesn't look to work in this case.